# Error while trying to set custom shape as background of widget

Tags: android, drawable, shapes

I want to set the background of the standard `TextView` in an Android project to a custom shape. The shape is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient android:type="radial"
              android:angle="90"
              android:startColor="#FF1EFFFF"
              android:endColor="#B01E90FF"
              android:centerColor="#201E90FF"
              android:centerX="0.5"
              android:centerY="1.0" />

</shape>
```

I try to set the custom shape by calling the `setBackgroundResource()` method on the textView.

```
TextView main = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
main.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient);
```

However, when I deploy this project on either a real device or on the Android Emulator, it won't start, and show this error:

`ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4369): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.android.gradienttest/org.android.gradienttest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>`

Trying to set the drawable by first getting it as a shape results in the same error.
By getting it as a shape I mean:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Shape shape = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient);
```

But as I said, this results in the same error... I know it gives the error when I try to load the shape, but the problem is I don't know why... So could anybody give me some help on this one? It must be a trivial mistake, as there isn't that much code involved...

Comment: The exception you got thrown says that your xml is wrong and has an error at line 7, be sure you're using gradient's attributes properly.

Comment: I thought I had, but I'll check them again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I forgot to add an attribute to my XML file. The attribute was `android:gradientRadius="180"`. By adding this attribute the gradient was being drawn correctly. Thanks user639183!

Answer (score 0):

CenterX and centerY are supposed to be integers. [This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) has a good listing of what all of the parameters will take.

Comment: That might be so, but in their example lower on the page, they specify that you have to use a number between 0 - 1.0 (floats). Besides, I used that page to start...

Comment: I actually looked at that for a few seconds and thought "Bad Android Developers..."